# C compiler with windows

Tags: c++, gcc

I am working with GCC compiler in Netbeans IDE but some thing I could not understand it , even I could not get answer in google search

Question :
why do we need to use Cygwin tool when working on GCC compiler in case our platform is Windows while we do not need this tool for Linux platform ?

Comment: You don't, it's just one of several options

Comment: Netbeans is a godawful C or C++ IDE - use CLion (free if you are a student), Code::Blocks (free, open source) or Visual Studio (free community editions). If you want a command line compiler on Windows, then https://nuwen.net/mingw.html is easy to install and use.

Answer (score 1):

## TL;DR

You don't need Cygwin to write C++ programs.

## Details

All you really need to write programs in C++ is a [tool chain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toolchain) that supports your target environment and a text editor.

Cygwin is a compatibility layer that brings a higher level of [POSIX compatibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX) than Windows systems normally provide to Windows.

Linux is an operating system that already supports POSIX, so no POSIX compatibility layer is required. Instead you may find yourself using [tools like wine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wine_(software)) to run Windows programs.

You do not need a Cygwin to use C++. You only need Cygwin if you want to build and run programs that have been written assuming POSIX compliance on a Windows-based system. If you write a program for Linux and it uses Linux system calls, odds are you will need Cygwin to compile and run it on Windows without replacing the system calls with their Windows equivalents.<sup>1</sup> Ditto if you are writing on Windows and intend to use the same code on Linux or any other POSIX compliant OS.

You can use other libraries, [Boost being a common option](https://www.boost.org), to provide cross-platform compatibility. If you are feeling adventurous or have a limited subset of non-portable system calls, you can also write your own layer to sit between your code and the target system

<sup>1</sup>Linux has its own calls in addition to POSIX support, so don't assume that you can always do this.

Answer (score -1):

You don't.

There are various *breeds* of the GNU C language compiler.
One is Cygwin.
Another is MinGW.  This compiler doesn't require Cygwin.
There are others.

The compiler needs to access operating system features.  Each breed accesses different OS facilities.

Comment: Why the downvote?  People need to leave comments explaining the reasons for downvotes.